# Combining two ffmpeg commands into single command

Tags: linux, command-line, video, ffmpeg

I want to combine two ffmpeg commands to single ffmpeg command.

Command 1

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -af "atempo=1.27,volume=1.6" -vf "setpts=PTS/1.27,scale=1280:720" -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 -g 60 -b:v 2500k -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -preset ultrafast output1.mp4
```

Command 2: the result "output1.mp4" on Command 1 will be input on this:

```
ffmpeg -i output1.mp4 -i background.mp4 -filter_complex "scale=850:478 [v1]; [1:v][v1]overlay=20:20" -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 -g 60 -b:v 2500k -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -preset ultrafast -preset ultrafast finish.mp4
```

Please help me in creating a single ffmpeg command!

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i background.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]atempo=1.27,volume=1.6[a];[0]setpts=PTS/1.27,scale=850:478[ovr];[1:v][ovr]overlay=20:20[v]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 -g 60 -b:v 2500k -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -preset ultrafast -preset ultrafast finish.mp4
```